# How to grow LVM ext2 (UEFI) boot partition @ /dev/sda1 ubuntu15.10 standalone install

Tags: boot, partitioning, kernel

I'm a complete newb when it comes to Linux as a whole, currently taking a Linux-101 class... so I decided to dive into it and rid my laptop of Win-8 ;-)

After much trouble with BIOS configurations,

I was able to clean install Ubuntu 15.10 (no other OS present in the Hard Drive) and decided to use the LVM partition option because it was supposed to be easier to manage partitions for future growth, plus the process was automated by the installer.

Everything working great until I was trying to install the latest security update release for Ubuntu,
and received an error message advising that my boot partition was almost full and that I could run "sudo apt-get clean" to free up some space, but that did not work.

I have found in this and other forums many answered questions that are very similar to mine but none are specifically addressing a **ext2 LVM UEFI partition mounted at /boot**. And at this point I'm really confused about what is the correct way to address this issue.

I suspect it may boil down to purging the contents of /boot leaving only the newest kernel and last known working kernel, but I have no Idea how to identify the last working kernel from the newest one.

- Should I try to increase the size of /dev/sda1 mounted at /boot?

( I believe is at maximum size according to Gparted) (231MiB max --
   155Mib used)

- Should I try to purge the contents of /boot? and if so, what is the correct way to do that?

(I believe the following info may be helpful)

**oscc@oscc-X551MA:~$ ls /boot**

abi-4.2.0-16-generic         *lost+found*

abi-4.2.0-21-generic         memtest86+.bin

abi-4.2.0-22-generic         memtest86+.elf

config-4.2.0-16-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin

config-4.2.0-21-generic      System.map-4.2.0-16-generic

config-4.2.0-22-generic      System.map-4.2.0-21-generic

*grub*                         System.map-4.2.0-22-generic

initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic

initrd.img-4.2.0-21-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-21-generic

initrd.img-4.2.0-22-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic

**oscc@oscc-X551MA:~$ uname -r**

4.2.0-22-generic

**oscc@oscc-X551MA:~$ uname -a**

Linux oscc-X551MA 4.2.0-22-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:57:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

- How can this problem be avoided in the future?